# yii2 model str_replace() for all attributes

Tags: php, yii2

`hello 's` gets saved in the db as `hello  \'s`

```
$eventDetail = Event::find()
                ->joinWith('eventQuestion', true)
                ->joinWith('eventQuestion.questionOption', true)
                ->where(['=','event.id',$id])
                ->one();
```

All data containing  `\'` should be replace with `'`

What should I change in the model(s) to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
public function retrieveById() {
$eventDetail = Event::find()
                ->joinWith('eventQuestion', true)
                ->joinWith('eventQuestion.questionOption', true)
                ->where(['event.id' =>$id])
                ->one();

// this or do a for loop if you want to loop through $eventDetail
$eventDetail->description = str_replace("\'","'", $eventDetail->description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, if we add any value with single quote, by default it add without backslash as you want to show in your view page.

Are you converting the single quote with backslash before saving or its  implicitly changing?

If its changing implicitly, you can check magic_quote_gpc setting in you PHP.ini. It should be off.  If your php version is less than 5.4 then you should change the magic_quote setting. if your PHP version is > 5.4 then there should be some other error.